# Search for text in multiple columns in multiple worksheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have 3 columns (Col1, Col2, Col3). All 3 columns are in their own worksheet (WS1, WS2, WS3).

I want to

1. search each cell in Col1
2. see if that cell matches anything within Col2 in WS2 then output "WS2"
3. if nothing in Col2, then see if that cell matches anything within Col3 in WS3 then output "WS3"

Hope this is enough information

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I cannot share this due to confidentiality

Comment: your question has multiple meanings... try to explain it better. if you can not share a copy of your actual sheet due to confidentiality, consider creating a dummy sheet with fake data which will mimic your setup so we could understand the structure of your dataset

Comment: Created dummy data for you: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kp2KKIJphrpySruLzhPZn_zoING8fnnBkXkDPAywZJ4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(
 IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'WS2'!A1:A, 1, 0)<>"", "WS2", ),
 IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'WS3'!A1:A, 1, 0)<>"", "WS3", )), ))
```

[image: 0]